# std::ofstream == NULL won't compile for -std=gnu++11, any workaround?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, stl

Consider the following code:

```
std::ostream file;
if( file == NULL ) std::cout << "Failed to open file" << std::endl;
```

It compiles perfectly when passing **-std=gnu11** (default from GCC 5.2), or just using
`gcc code.cpp -o a.out`.

It fails with **-std=gnu++11**, though:

```
no match for ‘operator==’ (operand types are ‘std::ofstream {aka std::basic_ofstream<char>}’ and ‘long int’)`
```

What is the simplest workaround?

Details:

I've got to use std=gnu++11 to have access to `shared_ptr` definitions. Furthermore, some code of mine is automatically generated and modifying the generator would incur in a reasonable effort - so I was wondering if someone could come up with simpler way to get rid of this "lack of compatibility".

Comment: `if (!file) std::cout << "Failed.";`

Comment: `-std=gnu11` is a c flag

Comment: `if( file == nullptr )`

Comment: @M.M,  why not? The stream has conversion to `void*`, AFAIK.

Comment: @SergeRogatch See my answer; This changed in C++11.

Comment: @SergeRogatch Even if it were legal, what sense does it make to compare an object to a pointer? Casting to `bool` is a little bit different and more meaningful.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The only reason why this ever compiled in the first place is because `std::ios`, which `ofstream` derives from, provided a non-explicit(!) `operator void*` prior to C++11. As of C++11, `explicit operator bool` is provided instead, which doesn't allow for implicit conversions as necessitated by your code. Instead, write

```
if (!file) std::cout << "Failed to open file" << std::endl;
```

Comment: This was rather useful. I was wondering if there would be some sort of flag or define that I could place in GCC command line to make this missing "operator==" visible again so that I didn't have to go through all of the source codes I've code.

Comment: I'd argue that the code was "wrong" to begin with.  An ofstream isn't a pointer (sure, it's convertible to a pointer), thus one should not be treating it like a pointer.

Comment: Also, since it was implicitly convertible to bool, you could write awful things like `int foo = file;` and it would happily compile.